# Visualforce page popup window

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a visualforce page (chat app) in my salesforce classic org. I want to use this as chat popup for every page in salesforce. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the one and only solution to open a custom popup on this page : https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

You can do this only from a Visualforce page, as you need to override a function call with Javascript code.